# Parsing content with Simple html dom from a table but with a condition

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, foreach, simple-html-dom

So I want to show in an 'echo' only the people that day which the situation is 'Yes', so let's assume today is only 'John' from my array list that have the situation 'Yes'.

```
$people = array('John', 'Greg', 'Mike', 'James', 'Jason');
$situation = array('Yes');
$html = str_get_html('<table class="mytab">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Situation</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="#">John</a>
    </td>
    <td class="s">
    <strong>Yes</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="#">Allan</a>
    </td>
    <td class="s">
    <strong>No</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="#">James</a>
    </td>
    <td class="s">
    <strong>No</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>');

$table = $html->find('table', 0);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $content= array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        $content[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $content;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)

    echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';


}
echo '</table>';
```

The code above is going to show:

```
John    Yes
Allan   No
James   No
```

It's driving me insane I can't figure it out!!
How can I search in the `<td>s` and get only the people 'Yes' that day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your $html is a valid XML string (meaning each tag closes properly, and has a parent tag, and no text outside tags), do this:

```
$html="<table>..";
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($html);

$result=array();
foreach($xml->tr as $tr){
    //you have your td, see what it has

    $name='';
    foreach($tr->td as $td) {

        if(isset($td->a))
            $name=$td->a;

        if(isset($td->strong) && $td->strong=='Yes'){
            $result[]=strval($name);
        }
    }
}

print_r($result); //this will have array with name of those where YES
Array
(
    [0] => John
)
```

**EDIT:** , if you have a well-known XML format of the html, no need to go and check every td. Here I remove nested loop, and reducing complexity from O(n2) to O(n).

```
$result=array();
foreach($xml->tr as $tr){

    //just in case see if a tag is there
    if(isset($tr->td[0]->a))
        $name = $tr->td[0]->a;

    $td2 = $tr->td[1];
    if(isset($td2->strong) && $td2->strong=='Yes'){
            $result[]=strval($name);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: nothing on `var_dump($td)` or `var_dump($tr)` , is xml right? apparently each tag is ok

Comment: Remove str_get_html() from $html. Only plain string in $html="<table>.." I also updated `foreach($xml->tr->td as $tr)` to `$td`, it was a typo

Comment: Solved, and executed.. I showed you the way in the beginning, but you wanted to have whole solution ))

Comment: nice bud, thanks! I've been struggling in this code for a while, now I'm gonna work to get data from a real website table

Comment: give me a sec, i will update the code without double loops. I have nested loops and their O(n2) complexity